# Set radio buttons group checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, attr

I trying to set the radio buttons group set checked by default, but I cant do this. 
I try these ways:

```
$('tr:first').closest('input:radio').attr('checked', true);


$('tr:first td input:radio').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('checked', true);
});

$('tr:first').closest('input:radio').attr('checked', true);
```

Please help me, how I can solve this issue.

Comment: `tr` can't have radio as parent so surely `closest()` will never work. Show your HTML.

Comment: Show us yout HTML markup also

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solve this:

```
$('tr:nth-child(2) td input:radio').each(function () {
       $(this).attr('checked', true);
   });
```

Thanks. Problem was in first row, where the header lay.

Answer (score 0):

`closest` will travel up in hierarchy (i.e. will search for parent element) and I think you are trying to find radio button inside `tr`. In this case, you can use `.find()` to get radio buttons, see below code -

```
$('tr:first').find('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', true);
```

NOTE - [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) introduced in jQuery 1.6, earliar [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) were using for changing propertises. Now `.prop()` is recommended to use instead of `.attr()`

Comment: `.attr('checked', true);` This should never been recommended for setting up element properties.

Answer (score 0):

To set the `checked` *property*, you use [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop), not `attr`. Your second code block is the closest to being correct (the two using `closest` don't make much sense, `closest` looks at *ancestor* elements and radio buttons can't contain table rows), but it would set `checked` on **all** radio buttons in the first row. If that's what you want, `prop` should do it:

```
$('tr:first td input:radio').each(function(){
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

```js
$('tr:first td input:radio').each(function(){
  $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label><input type="radio" name="group"> First row</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label><input type="radio" name="group"> Second row</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As [Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1209018/rajaprabhu-aravindasamy) points out in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294952/set-radio-buttons-group-checked/26295023#comment41259584_26295023) below, there's no need for `each` there:

```
$('tr:first td input:radio').prop('checked', true);
```

```js
$('tr:first td input:radio').prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label><input type="radio" name="group"> First row</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label><input type="radio" name="group"> Second row</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Side note: Using jQuery's selector extensions like `:first` and `:radio` significantly slows down the speed with which the `$()` function can find the elements, because jQuery can't offload the query to the browser's built-in selector engine. It doesn't matter for calls that aren't time-sensitive, of course, but for ones that are prefer using genuine CSS selectors. In this case, I believe `tr:first-child td input[type=radio]` would work provided your `tr` elements are in a `tbody`, `thead`, or `tfoot` (and if not, why not?) and you don't have any script-supporting elements prior to the first row in those elements (as those are the only two valid things to have in `tbody`, `thead`, or `tfoot`).

Comment: why didn't you suggest this? `$('tr:first td input:radio').prop('checked', true);`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: Good point. Forest-trees problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct syntax is

```
.prop('checked', true);
```

For whatever you are trying to do.
For example:

```
$('tr:first-child td input[type=radio]').each(function(){
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```